# Adobe AIR - How can I catch the event of image loading completed?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, image, air, onload-event

Core of my code is following:

```
var img:Image = new Image;  
img.source = 'http://..........';  
img.autoLoad = true;  
img.cachePolicy = 'on';

img.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(event:Event):void {  
    trace('Loaded!', img.source);  
});  
img.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, function(event:Event):void {  
    trace('Error!', img.source);  
});  
img.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, function(event:Event):void {  
    trace('Error!', img.source);  
});
```

I found that, the complete event does not occur for some images.
How can I catch complete event without signal leaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to load an image (or even another swf) the class to use is Loader. A quick example:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handlerFunction);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://somewhere/image.png"));
```

The only kind of tricky thing is that the events related to the loading are dispatched by the `loader.contentLoaderInfo` object, not the `loader` object.

And the always handy documentation:
[Loader Class](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found that the problem is in another part of my code. I checked that all two styles work well - "img.src = ..." and "using Loader".